# Nginx upstream reponse time occasionally very slow

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have a Ubuntu server that handles a lot of traffic and a lot of sites, occasionally Nginx takes a very long time to respond (20-30 seconds some times, and usually the request times out before that), initially i thought it was because of spikes of traffic in combination with Passenger not handling it well, but i have since replaced Passenger with Puma and load balanced the traffic and it is still happening.

Nginx Amplify sends me alerts of type `nginx.upstream.response.time` being too high, like 14 seconds for example.

Here's a general overview of the setup:

- server #1 (the one with the occasional slow response) has Nginx server blocks for 300+ sites.
- the server blocks `proxy_pass` to a load balancer server block (sites.myapp.com) also on server #1
- the load balancer splits the traffic between this server #1 (weight 1) and server #2 (weight 2) so that twice the amount of traffic goes to server #2
- on both server #1 and #2 i have another server block that receives the traffic from the load balancer and `proxy_pass` it to a unix socket used by Puma to serve an instance of my app.

You can find the relevant configs for all that below. I don't know how to troubleshoot this, but I am wondering if there are perhapse some configs in those server blocks that can be improved, like for example turning off proxy buffering or changing proxy buffer sizes?

Any idea what could be causing this and how to track down the problem? Because when Nginx becomes very slow to respond, the traffic doesnt even get rerouted to server 2.

Note that I know i should move all the sites server blocks/SSLs and the load balancer to a separate server so that at least when server 1 is going through that slow response phase, the traffic would still be passed on to server 2 but right now all i have are these two servers.

**Example site config:**

```
server {
  server_name www.somesite.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass                      https://sites.myapp.com;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header                Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_set_header                WLDOMAIN www.somesite.com;
    proxy_cookie_domain             .myapp.com .somesite.com;
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /sites/12345/$1 break;
  }
}
```

**Load Balancer simplified config:**

```
upstream cluster {
  ip_hash;
  server X.X.X.X:1234 weight=1; #internal ip of server #1
  server Y.Y.Y.Y:1234 weight=2; #internal ip of server #2
}

server {
  server_name sites.myapp.com;
  
  location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_pass http://cluster;

    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_429 http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

**Upstream simplified config:**

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///var/www/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 1234;

  root /var/www/myapp/public;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_pass http://puma;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

    proxy_redirect off;
  }

}
```

Note that this issue was already happening when the setup was just the various sites server blocks `proxy_pass`'ing the traffic to an upstream instead of having the load balancer in between them and the app being served by Passenger instead of Puma.

In case it matters, the app is Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after turning on debug output in Nginx it seems the problem was with the Nchan module in the `nginx-extras` package from Phusion Passenger, that one is buggy and would hang once in a while, once i got rid of Passenger (replaced with Puma) and replaced `nginx-extras` with `nginx` i haven't had that issue since.